# Post Query not working after updating to 4.1

Tags: wp-query, meta-query, updates, wordpress-version

After updating to Wordpress 4.1 I've noticed one of my more complex post queries has stopped working. It's querying from an events post type and returning posts with a standard timestamp of after today at midnight, or an end timestamp of after today at midnight (for multi-day events). Here is the query:

```
query_posts(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'events',
        'showposts' => -1,
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'meta_key' => '_ecmb_datetime',
        'meta_value' => strtotime('today midnight'),
        'meta_compare' => '>=',
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key' => '_ecmb_datetime_end',
                'value' => strtotime('today midnight'),
                'compare' => '>='
            )
        )
    )
);
```

I formed this query based on [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/136944/wp-query-using-meta-query-with-relation-or-and-orderby-meta-value-doesnt-work/136991). I had a look at [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/172817/meta-query-querrying-several-post-types-based-on-acf-fields-is-broken-after-upda) but I am not using `'meta_key' => 'meta_value'`, and to the part where the answerer says "meta_key isn't needed if you have a meta_query arg" I'm not sure that applies in the scenerio because I do want to query both key/values.

Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: Could [this](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/24093#comment:34) be the answer? I'll give it a go

Answer (score 0):

> I formed this query based on [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/136991/7355).

I would appear this is no longer the way to do it... I reformatted the query to look like this:

```
query_posts(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'events',
        'showposts' => -1,
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key' => '_ecmb_datetime',
                'value' => strtotime('today midnight'),
                'compare' => '>='
            ),
            array(
                'key' => '_ecmb_datetime_end',
                'value' => strtotime('today midnight'),
                'compare' => '>='
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Which seems to have solved the problem! If anyone has any other suggestions please feel free to share :)

Comment: You should stop usgin `query_posts`, use `WP_Query` instead.